# How do I run subprocess command that involves a 32-bit application from Python 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, odbc, subprocess

I've been scratching my head a lot around how to run a 32-bit application using subprocess in Python 3.4 64 bit (Windows 7 64 bit).

The application ("C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe") runs correctly from the terminal (cmd.exe). However, I can't get to run it using subprocess and given the errors, I suspect this is because the source I'm trying to read from is a user DSN that uses the MS Access 32-bit ODBC driver.

I tried several invocations of the subprocess call (e.g. with `shell=True`, `shell=False`, `executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe"`, etc)

Here's the first one, which raises a `PermissionError` exception:

```
query = subprocess.check_call(command,
    universal_newlines=True,
    env={"PGCLIENTENCODING": "WIN1252"},
    shell=False)
```

The other call, which uses `shell=True`, gives a more informative error message:

```
query = subprocess.call(" ".join(command),
                universal_newlines=True,
                env={"PGCLIENTENCODING": "WIN1252"},
                shell=True)

ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for PET4,
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `ODBC:FILE4' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  ...
  <skipped drivers>
  ...
  -> Walk
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
Error running 'ogr2ogr.exe' :

 Command '"C:/Program Files (x86)/GDAL/ogr2ogr.exe" --config PG_USE_COPY YES -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3175 -f PostgreSQL "PG:dbname=testdb_postgis_21 user=postgres host=localhost" ODBC:FILE4 -nln public.file4 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=gid -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=ON PLOTS' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

That same call, following `Command` at the end of the error message, runs like a charm if I execute it directly in the terminal.

Am I missing something in my subprocess call? Did I overlook important things I need to do? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't possibly want only `PGCLIENTENCODING` defined in the environment variables. That's extremely broken. Pass `env=env`, where `env` is `os.environ.copy()` with the added variable `env["PGCLIENTENCODING"] = "WIN1252"`.

Comment: Also, use a raw string for the path in an args list: `[r"C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe", "--config", ...]`. Don't use `shell=True`. The shell isn't required for this.

Comment: @eryksun You saved my day! Thanks also for the tip on `env`: does that mean the way I was doing it would result in `PGCLIENTENCODING` being the sole environment variable of my call? The only remaining point is, how can I programmatically turn my program string (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe"`) into a raw string? In my script this string is not hard-coded, it is a variable determined at runtime.

Comment: I thought you were entering the command line as a string literal in your script. It should be ok if it comes from a variable. I was worried about accidental uses of backslash escapes such as `\U` and `\t`. But the path in the error appears to use forward slashes, which should be fine as long as you don't use `shell=True`. The cmd shell prefers paths with backslash, but the Windows API itself will translate the slash to its native backslash.

Comment: Passing `env={"PGCLIENTENCODING": "WIN1252"}` makes that the only environment variable, except if you use `shell=True` cmd will add default values for `ComSpec`, `PATHEXT`, and `PROMPT`. Also, Windows always searches its system directories for loading DLLs and calling `CreateProcess` to run a program. However, programs that depend on standard environment variables will fail. For example, the Windows crypto API builds the path to its required DLLs dynamically based on the `SystemRoot` variable. Without this variable Python 3 won't start since it depends on this API.